# A not continuous map

Tags: general-topology, analysis

If we consider $E=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1 |f(t)|\,dt$ and we consider $T_\varphi(f)=\int_0^1 f(t) \varphi(t) \, dt$

How to choose a equence $f_n$ to prove that $T_\varphi$ is not continuous

Comment: what are your assumptions on $\varphi$?

Comment: What kind of function is $\varphi$. Is it continuous or just integrable?

Comment: Continuous , it is an element from E

Answer (score 3):

$$
|T_\varphi f|=\Big|\int_0^1 \!\varphi\, f \,dx\,\Big|\le\int_0^1 |\varphi| |\,f| \,dx
\le \max_{x\in[0,1]}|\varphi(x)|\int_0^1 |\,f|\,dx.
$$
So IT IS continuous, and
$$
\|T_\varphi\|\le \max_{x\in[0,1]}|\varphi(x)|.
$$

Comment: So it is a mistake in the exercise , is there an norm on which $T_{\varphi}$ is not continuous ? thank you

Comment: It should be a norm weaker than the $L^1-$norm.